# Composer global require "laravel/installer" failed

Tags: php, composer-php

I shifted from windows to xubuntu. I am using Laravel in windows and installed it via composer from the docs. Everything works fine there.

But when I shifted to xubuntu installed lamp php and mysql now everything works fine including the phpmyadmin.

I also installed composer and now trying to install laravel and this error shows up below.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I tried restarting my apache2 but still the same error for me.

here is the list of my config file when I typed php --ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your problem is in the ext-zip extension. You open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt install php7-zip.
```

See if it works out right there. OK
ps. I'm sorry for my english

Comment: On debian 8 (jessie) the command is: sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip