# Cannot install laravel in ubuntu (missing ext-zip)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

Help, I'm completely unable to install laravel on my kubuntu system. I had to compile php7.1 from scratch to get openssl and bzip to work, and I've checked every English result on Google for the error: 
"laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system"

Here is the complete error:

> gregory@alpha-centauri / $ composer global require "laravel/installer"
>
> Changed current directory to /home/gregory/.config/composer
>   Using version ^1.4 for laravel/installer
>   ./composer.json has been created
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - laravel/installer v1.4.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
> - laravel/installer v1.4.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.4.0, v1.4.1].
>
>   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
>     You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by > PHP in CLI mode.
>
> Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.

I've checked these other threads:

[Composer global require "laravel/installer" failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724719/composer-global-require-laravel-installer-failed)

[Can't install laravel installer via composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058457/cant-install-laravel-installer-via-composer)

But I already have php7.1-zip installed:

> gregory@alpha-centauri / $ sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
>   [sudo] password for gregory:
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> php7.1-zip is already the newest version 
>   (7.1.10-1+ubuntu17.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer 
>   required:
>
> gaviotatb gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gksu libapache2-mod-php7.0 libgaviotatb1 libgksu2-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-1
>     libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtop-2.0-10 libgtop2-common linux-headers-4.10.0-19 linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic
>     linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql python3-mako python3-markupsafe
>   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

I'm completely stuck and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please move to askubuntu. This is not a coding question.

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-7-0-ziparchive-library-is-missing-or-disabled)

Comment: Thanks @ljubadr, adding --enable-zip to my configure string worked after recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using version 7.1 of PHP under a Debian based Linux distro then do this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip
```